# Eigendecomposition of the Hadamard product of a rank one symmetric matrix and a positive definite symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector, hadamard-product

Is it possible to say anything about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix

$X = Y \circ xx^T$

where $Y$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix with known eigen-decomposition

$Y=U\Lambda U^T$

and $x$ is a vector. In particular if

$X=V\Phi V^T$

what is the relationship between $V,U$ and $\Lambda, \Phi$. And/or is there an $O(n^2)$ to compute $V,\Phi$ from $U,\Lambda$ where $n$ is the size of the matrices.

Comment: Note that $X = D Y D^T$, where $D=D^T$ is the diagonal matrix with the entries of $x$ on the diagonal -- this may be a more useful way to think about the problem. (That said, I don't know the answer.)

Comment: I had the same question come up - did you find an answer?

Comment: No not really. In the end I was able to recast my problem as  K + zz.T and use the techniques mentioned in 8.4.3 of Golub http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~jypan/Teaching/books/2013%20Matrix%20Computations%204th.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Ill check it out